# Realtime activity stream - architecture design

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm currently working on one interesting project to learn new technologies and practice a bit. There's a task - an activity stream. A list of notifications for every single user of an app.

After digging a bit, I've decided to go with PostgreSQL as a storage engine (as data integrity is quite important), node.js + socket.io and Redis to make everything working.

I've read some docs and was able to set u node.js + socket.io + Redis and publish a message to the channel successfully.

I have a question about the general idea:
- after successfull notification, should I send an AJAX request back to get some data from PHP? How is this issue usually solved?
- how to separate users notification - what to do to notify correct user? Separate Redis channels? This idea makes sense for me.
- I'd like to store the latest entries (let's say max. 100 per user) in Redis (a list with combination of LPUSH and LTRIM). What to store? HTML output? Only IDs from PGSQL database? My idea was to store only IDs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generally the point of using redis is really fast data access. If you store only the ids in redis, you then need to query for the data. If you are going to query anyways, just query for the last 100 posts and don't use redis.

Comment: Also, if you are using node for the data stream, why even use php? node can act as a web server (replacing apache) and can process logic (replacing php).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn it's a part of an app written in PHP. I've spent almost all day long today on reading, analyzing and looking for the best solution.